# Number of complete subgraphs in complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there anyone who have results on number of complete subgraphs in 9 vertices complete graph. I mean how many $K_3$ , $K_4$ etc

Answer (score 1):

Given the complete graph $K_9$, you can select any $3$ points to get a subgraph $K_3$. So there are exactly $\binom{9}{3}=84$ complete subgraphs of order $3$. You might want to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: That is obvious for triangles, as there are no diagonals. What about squares( it sould have two diagonals in a complete graph)? I don't think that it works in the same way

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, I thought you were only talking about a complete subgruphs of a complete graph. (And a square is not complete).

Comment: I got the idea. If you use binomials, it counts number of complete subgraphs in complete graphs (even squares with diagonals)